# SPARQL How To Get Individual By Class Name

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege

Please help me with the SPARQL query. I have an ontology with the class **'Verse'** as a subclass of **owl:Thing**.

The Individuals look like this:
[image: individual of Verse]

I need to do a SPARQL query, which will retrieve all the individuals according to the Verse (class name).

I have tried this, but it seems like this query is wrong:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
SELECT ?individual ?class
WHERE { 
    ?individual rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
    ?class rdf:type owl:Class .
}
```

ps: for download my ontology data, [here](https://teamtrainit.com/ontobible.owl)

Comment: you are asking for individuals of a given class, so why aren't you using the class URI? "which individuals belong to class Verse?" -> you are given the class `Verse` and the "belongs to" relation is via `rdf:type` - all that should be a variable is the individual indeed. It is just a single triple pattern

Comment: @UninformedUser, yes. i'm looking for list individuals of a given class. can you give me an example to get list of individuals using class URI?

Comment: your second triple pattern gets all things belonging to class `owl:Class` - so the principle is the same, just use your class instead and use obviously the other variable name for individuals.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the class name from your ontology.

```
PREFIX ontobible: <ur ontology IRI>

SELECT ?individual
WHERE {
    ?individual a ontobible:Verse .
}
```